# SSAS2005 - Distinct Count, but excluding null

Tags: ssas, mdx

Ok, here it goes.

I have a fact table (Fact_Sales).  Sometime, some sales are FLAGGED as SPECIAL (the whole invoice, not only a invoice line).  So the field IsSpecial is TRUE every invoice line of a particular invoice.

It is a TRUE/FALSE flag (so I would like using a Bit, in my fact table).

Here is an example of data :
*(forget the sample, I cant post a table, nor do an HTML table, nor formating text as a table with space)....just imagine it...*

Now, my SSAS2005 cube is good and works very well.

**First attempt: placing the InvoiceID or NULL in the FLAG field, and DISTINCT COUNT it**

In My first attempt, I put the InvoiceID or NULL in the IsSpecial field (that was not a byte), then do a DISTINCT COUNT, directly by adding my measure to a new measure group (so no MDX here). However, SSAS is not that bright, and count the NULL as an occurence.  So I always see '1' as the minimal value (finding a lot of "NULL" occurence, so having a count of 1).   I tried modifying the base measure source to Preserve Null, or ZeroOrBlank, but it will still shows me the value '1' everywhere (except when there is really a IsSpecial)..

**SECOND ATTEMPT : creating a MDX query that will DISTINCT count the IsSpecial 'measure'**

I read that here : http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/50286/calculated-member-to-get-distinct-count-on-a-condi.html.
My problem, is that there is no dimension to compare to.  I mean, WHAT will I be counting on?

**Third attempt : Creating a dimension.**
NO.  Note a road I want to go.  My customer dont want to split every of their measure into 2 members : Special invoice, and normal invoice.  They only wants 1 new measure, named "Nb of Special Invoice".

As you may have noticed, my SSAS capabilities is not that good, as I dont touched to that since 3-4 years, and my client want me to do that...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not want to create an attribute in dimension ? That would be the way to go: No need to write anything in the calculation script, fast access, easy to use for users.

Your SPECIAL flag is not a measure: it is not numeric with a meaningful aggregation like sum; it is a categorization, i. e. it should be put into an attribute having member values like e. g. "Special" and "Standard".

Even to implement the user interface as a measure "Nb of Invoices", the best way is to use an attribute, say `[Dim1].[SpecialFlag]`, and then implement the measure "Nb of Invoices" as a calculated measure using the tuple expression

```
([Measures].[Nb of Invoices], [Dim1].[SpecialFlag].[Special])
```

Comment: Yes I understand, you are right.  However, my customer want to have a measure for that.  They already have a measure "Nb of Invoices", and want to add the measure "Nb of Special Invoice".  So no need to drag N drop the dimension, no need split every other measures.

Comment: @Simon I extended my answer to cover that requirement.

Comment: Yes, and I can also Hide my dimension...So I will have all the requirements mets....   All of that because the Count Distinct function of SSAS include the NULL flag!  :)  thanks,